# Use different object property names for x and y axes

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have some data that is in this format:

```
[{"a": 123, "b": 234},{"a": 345, "b": 456}]
```

And I'm trying to represent this as a line chart with "a" as the x-axis, and "b" on the y-axis. But I can only get this to work if I convert the labels to "x" and "y", like this:

```
[{"x": 123, "y": 234},{"x": 345, "y": 456}]
```

That's clearly undesirable for large datasets. How can I get Highcharts to understand that I want to use different property names for the x and y axes?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way would be:

```
o[ new_key ] = o[ old_key ];
delete o[ old_key ];
```

Comment: I want a way for Highcharts to recognise my object properties without having to transform the data.

Comment: You are just moving pointers around, not the data. I don't think is expensive. A simple "retag" (or alias) like you want is basically the same.

Comment: Sure, but the data is 10k lines long. I know I can do it, I just don't want to. It's better not to.

Comment: So if you can not afford to do this, I think your problem has no solution. Because, there is probably better ways to "retag" but complexity probably is going to be the same (so you still have the same problem). BTW, 10k lines, doesn't seem to much

Answer (score 1):

You can map your data to the format required by Highcharts. For example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: data.map(dataEl => [dataEl.a, dataEl.b])
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z4yr7vxs/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data